# Is it possible to create a type or interface which is an Array with exactly "n" entries in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want to create an `Array` with maximum and minimum two entries.
Here is an example of expected behaviour:

```
const foo1: IShortArray = ['bar', 'baz', 'foz']; // TypeScript: error
const foo2: IShortArray = ['bar']; // TypeScript: error
const foo3: IShortArray = ['bar', 'baz']; // TypeScript: OK
```

I have tried something like this:

```
export interface IShortArray extends Array<string> {
  0: string;
  1: string;
}
```

Which does compile, but it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's already a primitive type for that called a Tuple. A Tuple allows you to define an array with a known number of items and just like an Array, you can store different data types in it.

It would look something like this:

```
type IShortArray = [string, string]

const foo1: IShortArray = ['bar', 'baz', 'foz']; // TS: error
const foo2: IShortArray = ['bar']; // TS: error
const foo3: IShortArray = ['bar', 'baz']; // TS: OK
```

Here's the [link to the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) for further reading.